# CAST failed when converting the varchar value to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, getting an unexpected 'Conversion failed' error.

Not quite sure how to describe this problem, so here is a simple example. When I parse some column in the database like this:

```
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(CurLovim,LEN(CurLovim)-1) As INT) FROM
(
 SELECT SUBSTRING(...) as CurLovim
 FROM [BackOfficeFut].[dbo].[our_orders]
 WHERE isin_id IN 
 (
  SELECT distinct isin_id 
  FROM [BackOfficeOpt].[dbo].[opt_sess_contents]
  WHERE base_isin_id = 335568
 )
)as t1
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UR' to data type int.

But if I change the condition on `isin_id` this way (it's equivalent):

```
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(CurLovim,LEN(CurLovim)-1) As INT) FROM
(
 SELECT SUBSTRING(...) as CurLovim
 FROM [BackOfficeFut].[dbo].[our_orders]
 WHERE isin_id != 335568
)as t1
```

the query works well.

I find it very strange because if I remove `CAST`, i.e. make queries `SELECT RIGHT(CurLovim,LEN(CurLovim)-1) FROM ...` they return exactly the same result.

What causes this error? Is this a known issue?

Comment: I think you need to have more info on this, might be some data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try testing the string to make sure it can be converted to a numeric?

Look at the isnumeric() function.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

```
-- Just play
USE tempdb;
GO

-- Create test table
CREATE TABLE T2
( C2 varchar(10) )
go

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('a2b');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('1ab');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('ab3');
GO

-- Check column 2 before converting
SELECT 
  CAST(
    CASE 
      WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(C2, 2, 1)) = 0 THEN 0
      ELSE SUBSTRING(C2, 2, 1)
    END AS INT) AS N2
FROM T2;
GO

-- Remove the table
DROP TABLE T2;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks! Using ISNUMERIC makes my queries even more confusing, but it works without such an error.

Comment: As a note, this will fail if the second character is a `'.'`.  You are better off in this case using `SUBSTRING(C2, 2, 1) between '0' and '9'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your field `base_isin_id` could have character values in it, that would explain the failure as it's doing a conversion in the `WHERE` clause of your first query.

Additionally, the queries aren't equivalent.
The first query you're looking for only the `isin_id`  where `base_isin_id = 335568` 
and the second you're getting all `isin_id` where `isin_id != 335568`

If the inside portion of your top query works, then there's must be an instance where the substring logic you're using doesn't result in a numeric value.  I think that's the best way to troubleshoot queries like this, isolate the parts that could be causing the issue and run them individually to pinpoint the error.

Comment: I understand that this queries aren't eqivalent in general, but it's the same in my particular case. Both queries works alike without cast, as I mentioned before.